# Avro deserialization error on schema evolution

Tags: java, deserialization, avro, spring-kafka

I have 2 schemas:

**schema1** (old schema) :

```
{
    "namespace": "com.org.package",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "EventModel",
    "fields": [
                    {
                        "name":"name",
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"long"
                    }
]
}
```

I updated the schema with a boolean field:

**schema2** (new schema) :

```
{
    "namespace": "com.org.package",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "EventModel",
    "fields": [
                    {
                        "name":"name",
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"id",
                        "type":"long"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"isActive",
                        "type":"boolean",
                        "default":false
                    }
]
}
```

The kafka topic has messages belonging to older schema(schema1). After the consumer schema is updated, consumer is not able to deserialise the older schema messages even after having a default value present in updated field.

According to Avro documentation:

```
if the reader's record schema has a field that contains a default value, and writer's schema does not have a field with the same name, then the reader should use the default value from its field.
if the reader's record schema has a field with no default value, and writer's schema does not have a field with the same name, an error is signalled.
```

[Avro doc](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution)

I am getting following error while deserialisation:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readBoolean(BinaryDecoder.java:140) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readBoolean(ValidatingDecoder.java:77) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:194) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:136) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:237) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:170) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144) ~[avro-1.9.1.jar!/:1.9.1]
```

Why is the default value not applied on consumer when the record is missing the field?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the type to `boolean` and `null` for `isActive` instead of just `boolean`. Something like:

```
{
    "name": "isActive",
    "type": ["boolean", "null"],
    "default": false
}
```

It will make schema backward compatible.

Comment: Hello!  Just a little gotcha -- the default value should match the *first* type in the union.  This schema is (wrongly) accepted by the Java SDK, and breaks in the more recent versions.  The quick fix is to put "boolean" before "null" in the list.

Comment: Good point, updated the answer @RyanSkraba